# Animate CC HTML5 canvas: how do I create a private/local variable in Actionscript?

Tags: html, actionscript-3, variables, canvas, local-variables

I'm using a variable to create a toggle-effect on a function. The only problem is that this code changes the variable globally, and not locally for each object using the function. I know what I have to do, just not how :)

Function:

```
var count;

function animateTarget($target, $rwFrame) {

        this.count = false;

        if(!count == true)
        {
            $target.gotoAndPlay(2);
            count=true;
        }
        else 
        {
            $target.gotoAndPlay($rwFrame); //playback from a different frame
            count=false;
        }
}
```

Call:

```
this.Foo_Btn.addEventListener("click", animateTarget.bind(this, this.Foo_target, 34));
```

Comment: Did not downvote but... _"and not locally for each object using the function"_ sounds like there's something else you're not telling us...  **(1)** What is _"each object"_ exactly, a Class object? a MovieClip object? an external loaded SWF object? **(2)** Does said object(s) have its own local / internal variable called count to be updated? **(3)** Could an `array` that simply holds the true/false _"count"_ states for each of your objects not achieve same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I got the answer from a friend (here with some updated variable names). Since it's JS, it reads the "clicked" as false, even though this is not stated. And by binding it to the object `target`it will check for each separate object that uses this function.

```
var clicked;
    function animateTarget(target, rwFrame) {

         if(!target.clicked)
         {
              target.gotoAndPlay(2);
              target.clicked = true;
         }
         else
         {
         target.gotoAndPlay(rwFrame);
         }
    }
```